# plotting a graph with date on the x-axis in R

Tags: r, date, plot

I am trying to do a plot with date on x-axis with an interval of 1 month and date values rotated for clarity.

```
r=runif(100)
d <- as.Date("2001/1/1") + 70*sort(r)
plot(d,r,type="l",xaxt="n")
axis.Date(1, at=seq(d[1],d[100],"month"), format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

This doesn't really work. I am trying to get something similar to the following graph:

[image: Reference graph]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does exactly what you ask the function to do.

Three months, three ticks.

```
> d[1]
[1] "2001-01-01"
> d[100]
[1] "2001-03-11"
```

Try this.

```
r=runif(100)
d <- as.Date("2001/1/1") + 70*sort(r)
plot(d,r,type="l",xaxt="n")
axis.Date(1, at = seq(d[1], d[100], length.out=25),
        labels = seq(d[1], d[100], length.out=25),
        format= "%m/%d/%Y", las = 2)
```

It should be easily adjusted to week/month/year. It's up to you to play with the `mar` parameter in `?par`.

Comment: This is cool.. I was confused with the attributes of the function. Thanks!

Comment: There is a small issue though. It hides part of the year label; how do I increase margin below it?

Comment: Remember `par(mfrow = c(2,2))`? `mar` works the same way. See `?par`.

Comment: got it, thanks. The current settings can be obtained from par().